# SQL trigger using old and updated values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I cannot figure out how to insert the old value and updated values from a SQL trigger into a table.  Say I have a table OrigTable and a table NewTable.  When I run a SQL trigger update statement, I want the column name Col1 in NewTable to be updated to the new value in the UPDATE statement where the Col1 value was equal to what the old value that was changed in NewTable Col1.

For example the statement would be UPDATE OrigTable SET Col1 = '10' WHERE Col1 = '2' and after this statement, the trigger would fire and run an UPDATE statement on NewTable and set Col1 in NewTable equal to 10 in every spot that Col1 is equal to 2.

Comment: Are you using sql-server or mysql? They are not the same thing. Also, why do you need to capture both old and new values at the same time? Why not just capture the old values. The new values will be either in the base table or in the next row in your audit table.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE NewTable
SET Col1 = (SELECT TOP 1 inserted.Col1 FROM inserted)
WHERE NewTable.Col1 = (SELECT TOP 1 deleted.Col1 FROM deleted)
```

This would work if you only update 1 row at a time.
SQL triggers only fire once per update query. So i would recommend that you use a Sql-Cursor for doing it. Try this one:

```
DECLARE @newValue nvarchar(max),
        @oldValue nvarchar(max)
DECLARE c1 CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT inserted.Col1, deleted.Col1
FROM inserted
JOIN deleted ON deleted.InsertYourPrimaryKeyHere = deleted.InsertYourPrimaryKeyHere
OPEN c1
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @newValue, @oldValue
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    UPDATE NewTable
    SET NewTable.Col1 = @newValue
    WHERE NewTable.Col1 = @oldValue
  END
  FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @newValue, @oldValue
END
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Add this code snipped into an insert-trigger on OrigTable